# Same column Date difference based on other field DAX POWER BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to calculate the date difference for all values in Field1 based on Field2 for example datediff(3/1/2020-2/1/2020) based on Field2 (c-b).

I have tried several ways but no luck so far.

[image: Input Table]

Comment: Please explain what those field1 and field2 stand for. It is barely understandable what you really want to do.

Comment: Field1 is the person id and field2 is the stage i want to find the difference in dates between different stages for individual person ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain a solution by adding 2 calculated columns:

First Calculated Column:

```
MinDate =
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( YourTable[Date] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( YourTable, YourTable[Field1] )
)
```

2nd Calculated Column:

```
Date_Difference =
DATEDIFF ( [MinDate], [Date], DAY )
```

End Result:

[image: 2_Calculated_Column]

Answer (score 1):

there is no minimum mentioned in the question, so i assume that you are looking for the difference of the previous stages.

```
Date Difference =
DATEDIFF (
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table' ),
            'Table'[Date] < EARLIER ( 'Table'[Date] )
                && EARLIER ( 'Table'[Field1] ) = 'Table'[Field1]
        )
    ),
    'Table'[Date],
    DAY
)
```